# Update data in distinct rows having same ID value

Tags: oracle, sql-update

There are two distinct table with the name SOURCE and target both have id AS common column  and I need to update the column in target table based on the value that is having in source table, however, when we I tried to update the columns in target table - 'SINGLE ROW SUBQUERY RETURNING MULTPILE VALUES' I need to bypass this error and need update all the column even if there are multiple id having same number.

```
Example:

Table - Source

ID      DESCRIPTION
123     PAIN
123     FEELING NERVOUS
123     NECK PAIN

TABLE - TARGET

ID      DESCRIPTION
123     NULL
123     NULL
123     NULL
```

Possible to way to update using Merge or Update DML and also using CTE (With Clause).

Comment: please show your sql attempt

Comment: The expected result is that your target table looks the same as the source table? What if there were only two rows for ID 123 in target table; what result would you expect then? And what if there were four rows for ID 123 in target table?

Comment: In that case, if you have any solution for that, request you to please share. And also, what if, values in the ID column of source and target are different then how it is possible to merge the data .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MERGE` statement and correlate using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
MERGE INTO target t
USING (
  SELECT t.ROWID AS rid,
         s.description
  FROM   (
           SELECT t.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY description) AS rn
           FROM   target t
         ) t
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT s.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY description) AS rn
           FROM   source s
         ) s
         ON (s.id = t.id AND s.rn = t.rn)
) s
ON (s.rid = t.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET description = s.description;
```

or a correlated `UPDATE` (using the same technique):

```sql
UPDATE target tgt
SET description = (
  SELECT s.description
  FROM   (
           SELECT t.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY description) AS rn
           FROM   target t
         ) t
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT s.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY description) AS rn
           FROM   source s
         ) s
         ON (s.id = t.id AND s.rn = t.rn)
  WHERE  t.ROWID = tgt.ROWID
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE source (ID, DESCRIPTION) AS
SELECT 123, 'PAIN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'FEELING NERVOUS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'NECK PAIN' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE target (id, description) as 
SELECT id, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(20)) FROM source;
```

Then after the `MERGE` or `UPDATE` the table contains:

| ID | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | FEELING NERVOUS |
| 123 | PAIN |
| 123 | NECK PAIN |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FTmD6YDl)